# Google share button - Change the text

Tags: php, button, share

I have google share button. The code is

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo base_url(); ?>property/prop_detail/<?php echo $prop_details->prop_id; ?>&t=<?php echo $prop_details->prop_title; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="_images/google-plus.png" alt="Google Plus" />
```

When I press the button (See Example)
http://www.mangosuntechrealestate.com/property/prop_detail/267

The google box comes up. It show the text from the search field Location on my homepage. How do I change the text to be the headline “Cozy 1 bed for RENT” (From example)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set both a title and meta description for your webpage (why doesn't it have a title?)

This can be simply done by adding the following directly below the `<head>` tag:

```
<title>Cosy 1 Bed for RENT</title>
<meta name="description" content="Cosy 1 Bed for RENT" />
```

Comment: It works..
But the reason it didn’t has a title is because then there will be duplicates. We write the title in the admin panel and there will be titles there are similar. It’s impossible to remember what is use and not. Duplicates are bad for SEO. That’s another challenge for this detail page I haven’t found a solution for…